# eigenvalues of a projection matrix proof with the determinant of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let X be a matrix n x d (n > d). 
Show that the eigenvalues of the projection matrix : X(X<sup>T</sup>X)<sup>-1</sup> X<sup>T</sup> are 0 and 1 and the multiplicity of 1 is d.

To do so calculate the determinant of the following block matrix (d+n)x(d+n) (4 blocks).
$$
\
  \begin{bmatrix}
    λI_n&X\\
    X^T&X^TX 
  \end{bmatrix}\,$$  where I<sub>n</sub> is the identity matrix *n*x*n*.

What I have done so far

I have used the following formula to calculate the determinant :
$$ det
\
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A&B\\
    C&D 
  \end{bmatrix}\,
 = (detA)det(D - C(A^-1)B$$
 det(λI<sub>n</sub>) = λ<sup>n</sup> (product of the elements on the diagonal), since det λI<sub>n</sub>≠0, λI<sub>n</sub> is invertible, λI<sub>n</sub><sup>-1</sup> =(λ<sup>-1</sup>)I<sub>n</sub>.

D - C(A^-1)B

=X<sup>T</sup>X - (X<sup>T</sup>(λ<sup>-1</sup>)(I<sub>n</sub>) X

=X<sup>T</sup>X - (X<sup>T</sup>(λ<sup>-1</sup>) X

=X<sup>T</sup>X - (X<sup>T</sup>(λ<sup>-1</sup>)(I<sub>n</sub>) X

=X<sup>T</sup>X[1-1\λ]

det (X<sup>T</sup>X - (X<sup>T</sup>(λ<sup>-1</sup>)(I<sub>n</sub>) X)

= [1 - 1/λ]<sup>d</sup>det(X^tX)

= [(λ-1)/λ]<sup>d</sup>det (X^tX)

I don't understand why do we need to calculate the determinant of that matrix to show that the eigenvalues are 0 and 1. (Where does that matrix comes from ?) Is it the characteristic equation ? If so then : 
the determinant of the bloc matrix is : λ<sup>n</sup>[(λ-1)/λ]<sup>d</sup>det (X^tX)

=  λ<sup>n-d</sup>(λ-1)<sup>d</sup>det (X^tX)

If I suppose det (X^tX) is a scalar then :

λ<sup>n-d</sup>(λ-1)<sup>d</sup>det (X^tX)

= λ<sup>n-d</sup>(λ-1)<sup>d</sup>k= 0

λ<sup>n-d</sup>(λ-1)<sup>d</sup> = 0
the eigenvalues are 0 with multiplicity of n-d and 1 with multiplicity of d.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: For the upper left block, did you mean to write $\lambda I_n$ instead of $XI_n$?

Comment: (related to question of @JimmyK4542) There is a problem: you cannot compute $XI_n$ because the dimensions of $X$ (n lines and p columns) and $I_n$ do not match. Moreover, even if the product is written $A:=I_nX$,  it will remain a rectangular matrix and $A^{-1}$ doesn't exist...

Comment: Yes indeed I made a mistake , sorry

Comment: If you do not *have to* use this determinant, it is easier to prove it just by definition. With some knowledge of minimal polynomial, even easier - from the equation $P^2=P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the eigenvalues of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ are all $0$ or $1$ and that the multiplicity of $1$ is $d$, you need to show that the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ are all $0$ or $1$ and that $1$ is a root of multiplicity $d$.

The characteristic polynomial of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is $\det[\lambda I_n - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T] = 0$.

It's hard to directly calculate $\det[\lambda I_n - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T]$ without knowing what the entries of $X$ are. So, we need to calculate it indirectly.

The trick they used to do this is to consider the block matrix $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda I_n&X\\X^T&X^TX\end{bmatrix}$.

There are two equivalant formulas for its determinant:

$\det\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix} = \det(D)\det(A-BD^{-1}C) = \det(A)\det(D-CA^{-1}B)$.

If we use the first formula, we get

$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda I_n&X\\X^T&X^TX\end{bmatrix} = \det(X^TX)\det(\lambda I_n - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)$.

Note that this is the characteristic polynomial of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ multiplied by $\det(X^TX)$.

If we use the second formula, we get

$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda I_n&X\\X^T&X^TX\end{bmatrix} = \det(\lambda I_n)\det(X^TX-X^T(\lambda I_n)^{-1}X) = \det(\lambda I_n)\det((1-\lambda^{-1})X^TX)$

$= \lambda^{n}(1-\lambda^{-1})^d\det(X^TX) = \lambda^{n-d}(\lambda-1)^{d}\det(X^TX)$.

Since these two formulas are equivalent, the two results are equal. Hence, $\det(X^TX)\det(\lambda I_n - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) = \lambda^{n-d}(\lambda-1)^{d}\det(X^TX)$.

Since $(X^TX)^{-1}$ exists, $\det(X^TX) \neq 0$, and so, we can divide both sides by $\det(X^TX)$ to get $\det(\lambda I_n - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) = \lambda^{n-d}(\lambda-1)^{d}$. Thus, the characteristic polynomial of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is $\lambda^{n-d}(\lambda-1)^{d}$, which has only $0$ and $1$ as roots, and $1$ has multiplicity $d$.

Comment: [+1] very interesting.

Comment: ^Indeed, I don't think I've seen this way of proving that the eigenvalues of an orthogonal projection matrix are all either $0$ or $1$.